# JSLint: What's An Edge?

Tags: javascript, parsing, jslint

I just stepped through the source code of JSLint. In the tree of the syntax parser, some tokens have a `edge` property. What's the meaning of the edge property in JSLint?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the edges in the [abstract syntax parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Not the nodes themselves, but the elements that connect the nodes.

For example, in a if/else branch, the condition is one node, the if branch is another, and the else branch a third node in the tree, with the edges annotated to mark the condition and code branches.